# Issues logging out in Angular 4 app using Auth0

Tags: angular, authentication, cookies, auth0

I have an Angular 4 app and am using Auth0 for login and signup. When you click login it takes you to Auth0's own page where you enter your credentials. Auth0 checks them and then sends you back to a callback url of your choice with a jwt in the url. I then store the tokens in localStorage.

Auth0 recommends that when you log out you simply delete the tokens and expiry date in the localStorage thus:

```
public logout(): void {
// Remove tokens and expiry time from localStorage
localStorage.removeItem('access_token');
localStorage.removeItem('id_token');
localStorage.removeItem('expires_at');
// Go back to the home route
this.router.navigate(['/signup']);
```

}

This works fine but then when I try to log in again I am not taken to Auth0's login page but instead the callback url with the token in it is automatically returned. This is not what I want because it means I am not really logged out. The only way to get around it is to delete "Cookies and other site data" in Chrome but as far as I can see there are no cookies (besides google analytics).

Can anyone explain what is happening here and how to fix it in the logout function above.

Comment: https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/saml/saml-configuration/logout

Hit the logout url to properly logout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to clearing the user's session at your application (by removing the tokens stored at `localStorage`), you might also want to clear the session created at Auth0 (i.e. the identity provider), by redirecting the user to `https://your-auth0-domain/v2/logout`.
Take a look at Auth0's logout doc for more information on sessions and details on the logout features.